# Change wp_mail SMTP settings for each E-Mail

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, smtp

I want to send mails using `wp_mail` function. I have multiple SMTP accounts login details. I want to send some mail using Account A and some using Account B. How can I send mails with different accounts? I saw `phpmailer_init` but it cannot be changed once set.

Comment: `phpmailer_init` will fire just before a message is sent, *every time*. You'll be fine to use that hook & change your SMTP settings on-the-fly, depending on whatever conditions.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Thanks! it worked for me. I thought it is one timer and cannot be changed